# Proof: Kolmogorov complexity of string concatenation

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, kolmogorov-complexity

Does there exist a universal constant $c$ such that for any strings $x, y$, we have: $$K(xy)\leq K(x) + K(y) + c$$
where $K(\cdot)$ denotes the Kolmogorov Complexity of a binary string and $xy$ means the concatenation of $x$ and $y$? I know the answer to this problem is no but I am seeking a proof for this, any hint?

Update: for reference, this is stated at the top of page 266 in Sipser's famous book "Introduction to the Theory of Computation", third edition, and is listed as Problem 6.19 in the book. I've tried to prove it but didn't succeed, just curious to know what proof technique should be used in order to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Kolmogorov complexity = length of shortest program to generate a string. Take the program generating x, add the fixed size code that makes it continue with a second program instead of halting, then add the second program generating y.

Comment: Yeah I understand such procedure, but note that the problem asks whether it holds for all possible strings $x$ and $y$. So a simple question is: since the length of the program generating $x$/$y$ can vary, fixed size code cannot be used to separate the description of programs generating $x$ and $y$. So this simple procedure will lead to an upper bound like $K(x) + K(y) + 2\min\{\log(K(x)), \log(K(y))\} + c$, not the one being asked.

Comment: @HanZhao Fixed-size code CAN be used to merge the two strings. Why not? In imperative programming, if `P` outputs $x$ and `Q` outputs $y$, then `P;Q` outputs $xy$, and is only a `;` longer. Or maybe you need something like `x:=P();y:=Q();return (x+y);`, which is also $O(1)$ longer. On Turing Machines something similar happens. (Note that the space complexity of the programs is irrelevant here, only its length matters)

Comment: @chi OK, so let's be a little bit more formal here. Let $< M_x, w_x>$ be the description of the program generating $x$, where $M_x$ is a binary string encoding of the TM and $w_x$ is an input binary string to $M_x$ so that $M_x(w_x) = x$. Make analogy definition to $y$. Now construct a new (universal) TM $M$ that takes the concatenation of $< M_x, w_x>$ and $< M_y, w_y>$ as input and outputs $xy$: $M$ simply simulates $M_x(w_x)$ and then simulates $M_y(w_y)$.

Comment: @chi But before $M$ can do so, it needs to precisely extract from its single input string which part corresponds to $x$/$y$. That means $M$ needs to know where $<M_x, w_x>$ ends. One way to do so is to prefix the length of $<M_x, w_x>$ at the beginning of the string so that $M$ knows how to parse exactly, and the length itself can be encoded using the doubling trick with length $2\log(K(x))$, i.e., for length 4 = 100, encode it as 110000, and use a following 01 as a separator.

Comment: @chi For this reason, and the fact that the fixed size code is also a string in $\{0,1\}^*$, $M$ does not know where the location of the fixed size code because the length of $<M_x, w_x>$ can vary.

Comment: @HanZhao You don't need $M$ at all! You only need to prove that given that TMs $M_x,M_y$ exist, then $M_{xy}$ exists and has a suitably bounded length. The transformation from $M_x,M_y$ to $M_{xy}$ is not done by a TM! You are trying to do much more that what it is needed to prove the above inequality.

Comment: @chi How do you know the existence of such TM $M_{xy}$? By construction from $M_x$ and $M_y$, right? But as I said above, here the $c$ in the inequality is a universal constant that does not depend on $x$ and $y$. A fixed size code cannot be used to separate $M_x$ and $M_y$ for all possible $x,y$, and that's the problem.

Comment: @HanZhao,  $M_{xy}$ can depend on $M_x$, $M_y$, and the length of $x$. It doesn't need to find the length of $x$, or have the length of $x$ provided as input; the length can be hard-coded in the source code of $M_{xy}$.  This is because we can choose a different $M_{xy}$ for each $x,y$; we don't need to construct a single TM $M$ that works for all $x,y$, but rather can design a different $M_{xy}$ for each possible choice of $x,y$.

Comment: @D.W. You can't hard-code the length of $x$ in $M_{xy}$, otherwise you get a $log(|x|)$ extra term in $K(M_{xy})$ which makes $c$ non constant -- this is what is puzzling Han. But we don't need to hardcode that, fortunately.

Comment: @chi, oh, right.  Good point.

Comment: @chi I mean, if we prove by construction from $M_x$ and $M_y$, then there needs to be some way for $M_{xy}$ to parse its single input string and extract both $M_x$ and $M_y$ from it precisely. What I want to mean is that this cannot be done by a simple fixed size code, which is also a binary string.

Comment: @HanZhao $M_x$ outputs $x$ on the empty input. $M_y$ outputs $y$ on the empty input. $M_{xy}$ outputs $xy$ on the empty input. $M_{xy}$ does not take as input the representation of $M_x$ and $M_y$, so it does not have to separate them. In the transition table of $M_{xy}$ there is, roughly, the disjoint union of the transition table of  $M_x$ and $M_y$, plus a few states/transitions more (constant number) to glue the resulting $x$ and $y$ together.

Comment: @chi I guess we might have a different definition of the Kolmogorov complexity then. From the definition given in the Sipser's book, a binary string $x$ is described by a TM $M$ and a binary input $w$ to $M$, otherwise to represent a string of $n$ bits, you might use at least $n$ states and $n$ rows in the transition table, which might result a description that is excessively long. See the first paragraph on Page 263 of the third edition, or Page 235 of the second edition: http://fuuu.be/polytech/INFOF408/Introduction-To-The-Theory-Of-Computation-Michael-Sipser.pdf

Comment: @chi At the very least, this shouldn't matter even if the input string is restricted to be empty: because $M_{xy}$ should at least take the description of $M_x$ and $M_y$ as input, and it needs to have a way to separate these two descriptions in a single input string. Note that I understand $M_{xy}$ can depend on $M_x$ and $M_y$, but the procedure of $M_{xy}$ itself should be fixed, and the only dependence appears as input to $M_{xy}$.

Comment: @HanZhao I finally see you point. With such definition, it seems you have to separate $x$ and $y$ in the input, which is not easy to do in constant overhead. At the moment, I can't see a solution. Indeed, according to Ex.6.25 in the Sipser book it can not be done.